# Where to find air core inductive coils?

Tags: coil, inductive

I have made a circuit to detect the material of a metallic cylinder.  It is able to discern aluminum brass and steel targets, and I used a hard drive voice coil for this.  This is for a machine I am developing for my small business, and I need to find a source of coils.  I don't want to wind my own by hand for quality control reasons, but I'd like to get as close to the hard drive coil as possible:

inside diameter: .5 to .65 inches
length: .1 to .2 inches
number of turns: 150 to 200

My GoogleFoo is failing me.  I can't seem to find anything in this range.

Comment: how about coplanar http://portal.groupkos.com/images/8/89/Wireless_Power_Transfer_Coil_Unit_Aah40702.jpg

Comment: In case you get stuck building your own:  http://gingerybookstore.com/CoilWindingMachine.html

Comment: What gauge wire? I don't think they would be very hard to make with a moderate investment in tooling.

Comment: usually any transformer company has a catalog for coil forms to make in any size. in this range and you'll be wise to use mm as most are int'l  , look for coil former (aka bobbin)  12~16mm D bobbin  x 5mm W for example

Comment: What frequency do you use?

Comment: I am using the built in touch interface on an ARM.  That interface pules at about 270Khz.

Answer (score 2):

Most coils of this sort are custom made as there is very little of a general market for them. You need to find a coil winding service. If you live in a metropolitan industrial area, you will probably find a local one. They will guide you thru the specification and build process. In general this is not a complex or costly proposition.

Answer (score 0):

You may be in luck here with wireless power coils coming to market now and in stock. ( and cheap)

http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2015/apr/advanced-wireless-power-parts-make-designing-chargers-easier-than-ever

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a really good idea, but my calculations show I need about .5mH, and the ones I see max out at about .05mH.  Everyone says to make my own, or have them made.  I'm checking various services now to see how much that would cost.

Comment: I've done what you are doing at much lower L 50uH and higher f,  What f are you using?  The common method is to use 3 frequencies or sweep it so one can discern ferrous permeability from Aluminum eddy current loss only

Comment: They are cheap enough.  I'll order one and see how it does.  Thanks.  I'm using a touch interface, and it is running at about 270Khz.  I'll dig into the library code and see if there are any options to tweak the frequency.

Comment: 50uH @270kHz is in the 200 Ohm range so for series resonant you need very low Z driver and parallel resonant a current source. We used a differential coil approach for eddy current sensing in steel. This is far more sensitive than a single coil and is used in all metal detectors. Then we measured with PLL's the quadrature currents with very high resolution.  Get the tri-coil as well